# Converting a complex variable to byte[] or Audioclip in Unity3d

Tags: c#, parsing, unity-game-engine, text-to-speech, att

I have a complex variable that is actually a wav file that I receive back from a request to AT&T. The variable is stored as ATT_MSSDK.TextToSpeechv1.TextToSpeechResponse (var). I would like Unity to be able to play this as an audioclip but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to do it. Do YOU have any suggestions? If I can some how parse this variable into a byte[] I could possible convert it into an audio clip but I can't figure out how to parse a complex non-primitive variable into byte[] or AudioClip. Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

`TextToSpeechResponse` object has `SpeechContent` property of type `byte[]` (https://wprod.code-api-att.com/MSSDK/PROD/docs/a00139.html).

So there's nothing to convert, just use that property value.

But you should probably check `ContentType` property first to determine audio format. You might need to decode it before playback.

Comment: Wow I don't know how I missed that. Thank you so much. If you happen to know of a good byte[] to AudioClip parser please let me know too, otherwise I think I can make it work with one of their samples used for a different function. Thanks again!

Comment: You probably should look into http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/400510/play-audio-from-byte-array.html